# Adding numbers present in similar-lines of file in bash

Tags: sorting, awk, scripting, uniq

I have file like this:

```
[host]$ cat /tmp/data
Breakfast 1
Lunch 1
Dinner 1
Dinner 1
Dinner 1
Lunch 1
Lunch 1
Dinner 1
```

I want output like:

```
Breakfast 1
Lunch 3
Dinner 4
```

How can I do it using command-line scripting awk/sed?

After doing following command I got:

```
[host]$ cat /tmp/data | sort | tr " " "\n"
Breakfast
1
Dinner
1
Dinner
1
Dinner
1
Dinner
1
Lunch
1
Lunch
1
Lunch
1
```

I am stuck at how to add these numbers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' /tmp/data
Dinner 4
Breakfast 1
Lunch 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, it will give you output in same order in which 1st field has come in Input_file.

```
awk '!a[$1]++{b[++count]=$1} {c[$1]++} END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print b[i],c[b[i]]}}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Breakfast 1
Lunch 3
Dinner 4
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code too now.

```
awk '
!a[$1]++{                    ##Checking condition if current lines first field is having only 1 count in array a then do following.
  b[++count]=$1              ##Creating an array named b whose index is variable count whose value is increasing number by 1 and value is $1.
}
{
  c[$1]++                    ##Creating an array named c whose index is $1 with increment value by 1.
}
END{                         ##Starting END block of awk code here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){     ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of count here.
    print b[i],c[b[i]]       ##Printing value of array b whose index is variable i and printing value of array c whose index is value of array b.
  }
}'  Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the number on each input line is always `1` you can ignore it:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'
Breakfast 1
Dinner 4
Lunch 3
```

or sorted by number of occurrences:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '{print $2, $1}'
Breakfast 1
Lunch 3
Dinner 4
```